# Is the dual of a left action a left coaction or a right coaction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G', G$ be groups and we have a left action $G' \times G \to G$. Which of the following is the dual of $G' \times G \to G$?

(1) $\mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[G'] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G]$, $f \mapsto \sum f_{(-1)} \otimes f_{(0)}$, $f(h.a)=f_{(-1)}(h)f_{(0)}(a)$, $h \in G'$, $a \in G$.

(2) $\mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G']$, $f \mapsto \sum f_{(0)} \otimes f_{(-1)}$, $f(h.a)=f_{(-1)}(h)f_{(0)}(a)$, $h \in G'$, $a \in G$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the dual of the map $G'\times G\to G$ is the map $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\mathbb{C}[G'\times G]$. The co-domain is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[G']\otimes\mathbb{C}[G]$, so I'd guess option (1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly unclear on your notation, but as remarked in the comments, the ($\mathbb C$-linear) dual of $$\alpha: (\mathbb C[G'] \otimes \mathbb C[G]) \to \mathbb C[G]$$ is $$\alpha^*: \mathbb C[G]^* \to (\mathbb C[G'] \otimes \mathbb C[G])^*$$ that takes $f \in \mathbb C[G]^*$ to $\alpha^*(f)(g' \otimes g) = f(g' \cdot g)$.

If we write $g^* \in \mathbb C[G]^*$ for the element dual to $g \in \mathbb C[G]$, then we see that $\alpha^*(g^*)(h' \otimes h) = g^*(h' \cdot h)$ so $$\alpha^*(g^*) = \sum_{h', h \text{ where } h' \cdot h = g} (h' \otimes h)^*$$

You can then identify $\mathbb C[G]$ and $\mathbb C[G'] \otimes \mathbb C[G]$ with their respective duals.